# Why does ExecutorService.submit(Runnable task) return Future<?> rather than Future<Void>?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, future, executorservice

The [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) has the following method:

[Future<?> submit(Runnable task)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-)

But since this `Future`'s `get` method will always return `null` wouldn't the following signature be more appropriate?

`Future<Void> submit(Runnable task)`

Answer (score 4):

Jdk 1.8 inside submit method implementation void is used while in jdk1.6 it was Object .My understanding is it is more appropriate to use void that's why it is changed in jdk1.7/1.8.Only to support the interface not changing it

```
 public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        RunnableFuture<Void> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
        execute(ftask);
        return ftask;
    }
```

and in JDK 1.6

```
 public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
       if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
       RunnableFuture<Object> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
       execute(ftask);
        return ftask;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I get that they don't want to change the interface afterwards. But why was it defined the way it is in the first place? `Void` type was available since [Java 1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html). So I guess it was just a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `Runnable`'s `run` method returns `void` primitive and not `Void` type. For that reason, `Future` cannot have a `Void` type and the solution was to make it a wildcard. Note that `Future` is from java 1.5 whereas `Runnable` is from 1.0. They wouldn't change `run`'s return type to conform to the `Future` due to legacy code reasons.

Comment: `Future<Void>`'s get method will always return `null` which is exactly what is asked for in this situation. `Future<?>` can return any object, when actually it will always return `null` in this particular case, as stated in the javadoc of the `submit` method. So `Future<Void>` would have been the right choice here. Analogous, if `run` would have returned `double` a `Future<Double>` would be appropriate rather than a `Future<?>`.

Answer (score -1):

Because `ExecutorService`'s `Future` interface is created for get a return data from another thread not for just run it.
`Future<Void> submit(Runnable task)` works same as `new Thread(runnable).start()`, the return of `null` is meaningfull for some cases.

**Edit :**
Think you need to close a thread after 20 minutes. How would you do that when you have a return value `void` ?

```
Future<Void> future = execService.submit(operation);
execService.shutdown();
opResult = future.get(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This code must give error because there is no return on `future`. But if it return a null the `execService` controller object will know the `shutdown` is happened. Or if it not return anything in 20 min `execService.shutdownNow()` can be used.

Comment: If it was `Future<Void>`, it would work exactly the same way as it does now.

Comment: How could you return Void from call method ?

Comment: `Void method() { return null; }`

Comment: return null is not same with void signed method. Op is asking for no return value

Comment: First, I mean `java.lang.Void` (abbreviated as `Void` after imports), not `void`, same as OP does. Second, OP isn't asking for no return value.

Comment: I'm talking about java.lang.Void. If you declare Void you must return null. But OP's problem is with returned null value. Returning null is not true for Void logic.

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız my problem is not with returned `null` value but with the method signature. `Future<Void>` would be more appropriate for a `Future` that always returns null.